# How to reproduce Visual Studio ClickOnce publish from command line

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, clickonce, visual-studio-2022

[image: The Publish button in Visual Studio 2022]

I have been publishing my app by clicking the Publish button in the VS2022 project Publish tool. I want to recreate the same behaviour from the command line.

My C# project targets .NET 6.0, and my .pubxml has `<PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol>`.

[These docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#feedback) sound like they should document what I need, but the suggested variations on `msbuild /target:publish` absolutely do not produce the same result as clicking the button in VS:

- The `<PublishDir>` and `<PublishUrl>` from the .pubxml are ignored.
- The `<ApplicationRevision>` is not updated even when `<IsRevisionIncremented>` is true.
- Most importantly, the output is missing the main `MyApp.application` file and the `Application Files` folder.

Comment: I writed code just now to achieve the feature you want. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

A script to achieve your requirements:

```
#find the .csproj file
$csproj = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.csproj

# #return the name of the project
$projectname = $csproj.Name -replace ".csproj",""

$publishdir = "bin\publish"
$publishXML = "Properties\PublishProfiles\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml"

#remove all content of the "$publishdir/Application Files" directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $publishdir"\Application Files" | Remove-Item -Recurse

MSBuild.exe /target:publish /p:COnfiguration=publish /p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml /p:PublishDir=$publishdir

#remove all files or directories except setup.exe, projectname.application and the directory "Application Files"
Get-ChildItem -Path $publishdir | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "setup.exe" -and $_.Name -ne $projectname+".application" -and $_.Name -ne "Application Files"} | Remove-Item -Recurse

#get the content of Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationRevision in the .pubxml file
$pubxmldata = [xml](Get-Content $publishXML)
$ApplicationRevision = $pubxmldata.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationRevision

#increment the ApplicationRevision value
$ApplicationRevision = [int]$ApplicationRevision + 1

#replace the ApplicationRevision value in the .pubxml file
$pubxmldata.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationRevision = [string]$ApplicationRevision

#save the .pubxml file
$pubxmldata.Save($publishXML)
```

**Original Answer:**

> The `<PublishDir>` and `<PublishUrl>` from the .pubxml are ignored.

> The `<ApplicationRevision>` is not updated even when 
> is true.

> Most importantly, the output is missing the main
> MyApp.application file and the Application Files folder.

For the first and the third requirement, using the below command will solve the issue:

```
msbuild -t:restore 

msbuild /target:publish /p:Configuration=publish /p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\ClickOnceProfile.pubxml /p:PublishDir=bin\Release\net6.0-windows\app.publish\ /p:PublishUrl="bin\publish\"
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

For the second requirement, the value didn't increase is totally expected, because it is not automatically incremented for builds performed at the command-line. See this official document:

[Publish Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#publish-properties)

[image]

Increase this value need based on IDE, pure msbuild command can't achieve this.

Comment: Many thanks for this useful information. Sounds like with a bit of extra scripting, the PublishUrl and PublishDir could be read from the .pubxml and passed on the command line. As for updating ApplicationRevision, sounds like that also needs some custom scripting. But on the third point about missing files, in your solution there now seem to be a bunch of _extra_ files that shouldn't be there! Only setup.exe and WinFormsApp1.application would exist when clicking the Publish button inside Visual Studio 

Comment: @HughW Hi, Hugh, I write a auto code just now, a powershell script, you just need to run it in your project folder, then it will get the same result as UI and the ApplicationRevision will also increase automatically. i just provide an example with detailed comment of each step, you can change it if you need more feature. :)

Comment: Wow thank you for all your effort!

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT: Thanks man!! Two things arose at my place: I had to open an admin shell, in which msbuild was unknown. After I added this to my env, It uses the local user's app for the the save arg, I had to wrap like ```$pubxmldata.Save((Get-Item -Path $publishXML -Verbose).FullName)```.
Now I have a question, how can I also bring in a publishing http site here (so that msbuild produces something like publish.htm...) And why can't I just use all the info from ```Clickonce.pubxml``` there, it is all defined there?